# Convert a thumb drive to flash drive

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive

I have two USBs, both Kingston DT101 G2, 8GB. Both FAT32.

When I connect my USBs into my machine (Ubuntu), one is detected as a "Thumb drive"  and the other is detected as a "Flash drive".

[image]

I wonder:

- Is there any way I can convert my thumb drive into a flash drive?

PS. The reason I want to do this is that I have a special case where I use these USBs to boot a live version of Ubuntu. However, the thumb drive freezes or loops at the machine company logo screen on some computers.

Comment: I really doubt that changing what Ubuntu calls this will in any way affect the issue you're having. My guess is that you have just set one of the two to be bootable and not the other.

Comment: If you format the "thumb" drive entirely and re-create the boot disk using whatever tool you used and see what happens... the bootdisk creator SHOULD set the device to be bootable (that's the whole point of the application!)... you then choose from your BIOS startup devices which disk to boot from.

Comment: Are you sure they are the same? What's the output of `lsusb`?